# rich:dataScroller not working properly when application is deployed in glassfish 3.0.1

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, glassfish-3

I have an application which uses rich:dataScroller. I've tried deploying it on Glassfish 3.1.1 and it worked fine. However, when I tried deploying the same application in Glassfish 3.0.1, it isn't working properly.

I wonder if there's a known compatibility issue with the said component in GF3.0.1? Btw, I am using Richfaces 3.3.1

Hope someone can help me with this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The difference between GF 3.0.1 and 3.1.1 is the version of the integrated JSF implementation [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net). GF 3.0.1 uses Mojarra 2.0.2 which is a rather early version which may have some dangerous bugs blocking your application from functioning properly. GF 3.1.1 uses Mojarra 2.1.3 which is almost one more year of bugfixing/enhancing.

If you can't change the target server version, then you can always bundle a newer version of Mojarra in the webapp itself. Just drop the `javax-faces.jar` file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and edit the `/WEB-INF/sun-web.xml` (or for GF 3.1.x, the `glassfish-web.xml`), to add the following lines in order to get it to load the WAR-bundled JSF instead:

```xml
<class-loader delegate="false" />
<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />
```